# Intermittent 200 response appended with 400 response

Tags: asp.net, http, tcp, azure-web-app-service, wireshark

I'm experiencing a very concerning problem that I'm hoping someone more knowledgeable in web protocols may be able to help with. Unfortunately, I cannot share complete .pcapng files because they contain sensitive information. I tried to sanitize them with TraceWrangler, but I think because I needed to decrypt the 802.11 packets with an SSID and password to even view them in Wireshark, TraceWrangler is unable to modify them. Anyway, I digress...

The general scenario is that we have devices in the field that call an endpoint periodically, and by periodically I mean every time they want to connect to any of our services. Recently, we began seeing a spike in failures/retries coming from our devices using this service. Upon further investigation, the problem was narrowed down to a non-compliant http request. The request the device was making contained an extraneous trailing CRLF in its headers. Removing that stops the unexpected behavior from ever occurring.

So, problem solved, right? Well, this specific application hasn't changed in years, and because this is seemingly new behavior, I am trying to ascertain more details on the problem, specifically the intermittent nature of it. Although simply removing the trailing CRLF from the request eliminates the problem, it doesn't explain the non-deterministic behavior of it. This is where I am looking for some help.

Here is what I can provide of the Wireshark capture: https://ibb.co/Jdh1mt5

On the left side, you can see that the response contains the expected 200 and payload, but another 400 response is appended directly to the end of the response.

Fortunately, the device will instantly retry in this scenario, and continue to do so until it receives a response it understands.

On the right, which begins before the last stream ends, the device retries again and the service returns a 200 without the appended 400.

I've exported both of these requests and diff checked them, I see almost nothing different between them worth noting. The one thing I did find is that in the request that results in the double response, Wireshark shows it is `[Http Request 1/2]`. However, the 2nd part of the request doesn't appear in Wireshark. https://ibb.co/8BgfQSB

The request which gets a response without the trailing 400 is shown as `[Http Request 1/1]` in Wireshark. The size of these requests is identical, so it doesn't appear at first glance that anything at all is different between them. https://ibb.co/CMyDFp9

I'm wondering now if there's anything useful to be gleaned out of the TCP traffic during these streams. My understanding of TCP behavior is surface-level at best. I've done some reading very recently, but maybe someone here may be able to expediate my understanding of the information I need to know. Is it possible there is any answer to this intermittent behavior within these TCP exchanges?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have now been able to successfully reproduce the problem using Burp Suite.

By setting the Repeater options to not automatically update the `Content-Length` header of the request, I was able to add trailing CRLFs with an incorrect `Content-Length` of `0`. With this, the responses mimicked the behavior we are seeing in the field. The request sometimes only returns a single 200, and sometimes returns a 200 followed by a 400.

single 200: https://ibb.co/vJtbc79

trailing 400: https://ibb.co/sHwZdv1

Something I noticed on the single 200 responses, is that the server seems to hang for a moment before I receive it. The double responses are very snappy.

So, with that, is there anything that can be done on the IIS/App Service side to correct this for devices running old firmware?

Comment: Let me guess: on your server side you have a reverse proxy in front of your web/application server, and you recenty changed something there (perhaps even only software version)?

Comment: @DusanBajic The App Service is being called directly by the device, there is nothing in front of it.

Comment: I see. Did the App service change (perhaps internally, in the http request handling part)?

Comment: @DusanBajic We began noticing this problem around April 13, 2022. We've been in discussions with Microsoft to try and understand if there was any underlying changes to the App Service around that time, but according to their own change logs - it doesn't look like it.

Comment: @DusanBajic I would like to add that as of right now, why this started occurring is a secondary concern, what's more important is why this isn't failing 100% of the time.

Comment: I can't help further unfortunately, but perhaps this points you in right direction: such inconsistencies in the way webservers handle "fishy" http headers are the cause of "HTTP desync" attacks, described for example here https://blog.securityinnovation.com/http-desync-request-smuggling-attacks